# mx:List horizontal scroll is always visible when set to auto

Tags: flex4, horizontal-scrolling

My mx:list ALWAYS shows the scrollbar even though the policy is set to Auto.  How can I get it to truly be Auto and disappear when not needed?
Here is the code:

```
<fx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
    private function initFoo():void 
    {
      foo.maxHorizontalScrollPosition=foo.columnWidth;
    }
  ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:VGroup width="100%">
  <mx:List id="foo" width="100%" horizontalScrollPolicy="{ScrollPolicy.AUTO}" creationComplete="initFoo()" >
    <mx:dataProvider>
      <fx:String>text</fx:String>               
    </mx:dataProvider>
  </mx:List>
</s:VGroup>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem seems to occur because you are setting the `maxHorizontalScrollPosition`. If you don't do that, the list behaves as you would expect (no scrollbars unless they're actually needed).

You're also using the list's `columnWidth` property, but the [docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#columnWidth) say that is only used the the old `<mx:TileList />` and `<mx:HorizontalList />` components -- no point in using it with with a `<mx:List />`. *The default value is for `columnWidth` is 50 and that is why you're seeing the scroll bars.*

If you set the `columnWidth` on the list to say 500, the scrollbars disappear. But again, I suggest not using the `maxHorizontalScrollPosition` or `columnWidth` at all.

Frankly, I'm not sure what the purpose setting the `maxHorizontalScrollPosition` is. If there are scroll bars, don't you want to allow the user to scroll to whatever the end is? I've never used this property before, and the more I think about it, it seems a little superfluous that the Flex SDK developers even created such a property -- again, why have scroll bars but then not allow the user to scroll to the end? I'm sure there's some reason :)

Finally, you might be better off using a `<s:List />` rather than `<mx:List />` -- you're using the Spark components already in the `<s:VGroup />`, so there's no reason to use MX for the list. If you use the Spark list, your code changes slightly (some of those properties are no longer relevant), but you should be able to achieve the same result you're after.